# Laravel: Route::resource nombre de parametro

Tags: php, laravel

me encuentro con el siguiente problema en Laravel 6.

Tengo las siguientes rutas

```
Route::name('admin.')->prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    // Users
    Route::resource('users', 'Admin\UserController', [
        'except' => 'destroy'
    ]);
    // Aeronaves
    Route::resource('aeronaves', 'Admin\AeronaveController', [
        'except' => 'destroy',
        'parameters' => [
            'aeronafe' => 'aeronave'
        ]
    ]);
});
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es cambiar el parámetro 'aeronafe' que me crea Laravel por defecto por 'aeronave', pero no lo logro. Al ejecutar el comando route:list me sale lo siguiente:

```
admin/aeronaves/create
admin/aeronaves/{aeronafe}
admin/aeronaves/{aeronafe}/edit
...
```

Lo correcto sería que salieran así:

```
admin/aeronaves/create
admin/aeronaves/{aeronave}
admin/aeronaves/{aeronave}/edit
...
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: porque preocuparse por algo tan trivial??, lo que intentas no deberia de ser relevante para el desarrollo de tu sistema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aquí, estás trabajando con el recurso `'aeronaves'`, por lo que en lugar de intentar cambiar el nombre del parámetro `'aeronafe'` a `'aeronave'`, debes especificar que el parámetro para el recurso `'aeronaves'` debe ser `'aeronave'`. Entonces tu código quedaría así:

```
// Aeronaves
Route::resource('aeronaves', 'Admin\AeronaveController', [
    'except' => 'destroy',
    'parameters' => [
        'aeronaves' => 'aeronave' // donde 'aeronaves' es el recurso, y 'aeronave' el nombre del parámetro
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Efectivamente, esto resolvió mi problema. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Intenta borrar la cache, con el siguiente comando:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Otra cosa que puedes realizar es limpiar la cache de todo tu aplicativo:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

has probado pasándolo solo como array?

```
// Aeronaves
    Route::resource('aeronaves', 'Admin\AeronaveController', [
       'except' => 'destroy',
       'parameters' => ['aeronave']
    ]);
```

no he trabajado esa forma, pero creo que podria ayudarte, igualmente puedes tratar a 
    borrar caching

```
php artisan route:cache
```

O

```
php artisan cache:clear
```